# Alter message status per content type

Tags: 7, status-messages

After hours trying to figure it out, no way ! What am I doing wrong ?

```
function alter_appointment_message_form_node_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id)
{
     if($form['#node']->type=="appointment_request")
     {
       drupal_get_messages('status'); // Flush default simplenews status message
       drupal_set_message(t('An appointment has been requested'), 'status');
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what is actually happening that does not match with your expectations?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wanted to alter message after node creation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to show a message after submitting the form. (But as Pierre commented, please be clear in what you want and do not make us assume things.) `hook_form_alter()` works during the building of the form. Your code probably works, but there is no message generated yet.

Instead, use `hook_form_alter` to add a new submit callback and place your code in there. Somewhat like this:

```
function alter_appointment_message_form_node_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id)
{
  $form['#submit'][] = 'alter_appointment_message_post_submit';
}

/**
 * Custom submit callback.
 */
function alter_appointment_message_post_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 if($form['#node']->type == "appointment_request") {
   drupal_get_messages('status'); // Flush default simplenews status message
   drupal_set_message(t('An appointment has been requested'), 'status');
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that works but how can I disable the original message then ? I have a rule with a custom message set, I'm gonna try disabling it. Edit So know the original message is still there. So basically I have the same behavior as if I had made a rule ...

Comment: Drupal processes hooks in the order it finds them; which means this function might be called before the others. You could try to [increase your module weight](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-update-a-modules-weight) or the weight of this specific hook by using [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x).

Comment: Ok, thanks I'm gonna check that. But also the message is displayed when editing nodes from that content type, and that's not really what I want to ...

Comment: `if ($form['#node']->type == "appointment_request" && $form['#node']->is_new)`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I am adding another answer which is probably easier and closer to what you want.

Use [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x) instead. That only runs after saving a new node, and also runs after the node has been created and the creation message is defined. You only need:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function alter_appointment_message_node_insert($node) {
 if($node->type == "appointment_request") {
   drupal_get_messages('status'); // Flush default simplenews status message
   drupal_set_message(t('An appointment has been requested'), 'status');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a module (D7) for that [Custom Submit Messages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/csm), from module page:

> Allows users to set custom submit messages for different node types via the Drupal UI. So, rather than being stuck with "Page title has been saved", "Page title has been updated" and "Page title has been deleted" the user can set custom submit messages. In addition to this, CSM allows you to change the title of the node creation page. CSM allows both of these things to be set separately for each language your Drupal site is running in, and for whatever user roles are defined on your site.